# In MS Visio, add depth to content using layers

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2010

I have a process flow-chart in MS Visio.  I want to present "what-if" paths; this will be an alternative or secondary view.

This seemed like a natural use for **layers**.  But looking at the Help files, layers are for dealing with *format*, not *content*.  I am advised to use them for "organizing my shapes."  This seems silly because that's what stencils are for.

I don't see any suggestions for putting layers to semantic use.  It's surprising because I'd have thought the precedent for layers in Visio is their use in CAD, where they are indispensible for organizing content.

Are layers suitable for my goal?  If yes, any tips?  If no, what is a good approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After substantial effort, here is my own answer:  Layers in MS Visio are, indeed, not useful for organizing by content.

There is no way to assign new shapes/objects to a created layer; they are assigned to their default layer.  For example, a new connector goes to the "connectors" layer.  Obviously this allows no efficient workflow for adding content while maintaining content-oriented layers.  (Please let me know if I am missing something.)

One of my general disappointments with Visio is that, functionally, it seems to reflect Power Point more than Excel.  I get the feeling on-screen presentation is the only intended purpose; analytical functions are missing, or feel like an afterthought.

Answer (score 1):

I have used layers for semantics though I'd have to say that they aren't the easiest to use.

When MS talk about organising, they are not referring to the masters that you get in your stencils. Rather, layers are used for organising the objects on the page.

So you might put the connectors in one layer and the boxes in another and swimlanes in another. As your diagrams get more complex, it can be helpful to turn off some of the layers.

In your case, you might well be able to use layers for what-if paths, worth a try. Just be prepared to spend some time getting familiar with the various settings and options.

Comment: I understand your point that a stencil has a distinct purpose (and different use) than a shape-oriented layer. Your answer seems to confirm layers are more suitable for formatting than content. Perhaps I will try anyway. If you can offer specific insights to reduce the 'learning-curve' for settings and options, I'd be grateful for that.

Answer (score 0):

Create a layer with a suitable name, then put the shapes and connectors you want to associate with that "what-if"  on that layer (and remove them from any other layers.
Now you can turn on/off the visiblity of that layer.

**Addition 2nd July 2014**

I've created an example file and put in my Dropbox

[demo of Visio layers to control visibility](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mct91lrbstat8mb/layers.vsd)

It contains 3 what-if layers that can be turned on or off using layer visibility. Layer what-if 2 is off and the other 2 are on. Hope this does what you want.

Comment: I cannot see that this applies to my question, so consider this a down-vote.

Comment: I'll create an example for you then - wait til Monday, it's quite simple.